QuestDB & Python, Polars or Pandas?
I am trying to follow QuestDB blog to build a trading bot (https://questdb.io/blog/scaling-trading-bot-with-time-series-database/) and I want to know what is main difference between pandas and polars.
Is one better than the other for QuestDB? Does it matter?

At the moment QuestDB has better integration with Pandas, as it can send a dataframe directly from Python. When using polars, you would need to convert the polars dataframe to a Pandas dataframe, or iterate over the rows().
There is also a questdb repo for querying data and converting efficiently into pandas or numpy objects https://github.com/questdb/py-questdb-query
QuestDB will have Arrow/ADBC support in the future, and by then Polars might be a better option, but as of now it seems Pandas has some advantages for the native integrations
